# Is it a good CSS practice to stack generalizes classes rather than build specific ones?

Tags: css

I'm wondering in CSS, whether it's a good practice to **stack** many different *generalized* classes rather than building new classes for each situation to achieve the same result.

**For example, with detailed classes, which is how I normally write CSS:**

HTML

```
<div class="profile-page">
<div class="profile-page-left">
    <img src="" class="profile-picture"/>
    <p class="about-me-section">Who Cares</p>
</div>
<div class="profile-page-right">
   <p class="name"><span class="fname">John</span> Thomas</p>
   <p class="title">Boss</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.profile-page{
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   width:800px;
}

.profile-page-left{
   float:left;
   width:50%;
}

.profile-page-right{
   float:right;
   width:50%;
}

/* etc */
```

---

**And now, the same result with generalized classes:**

HTML

```
<div class="center width-800">
<div class="float-left width-Half">
    <img src="" class="width-400 height-400 border-width-3 border-color-blue"/>
    <p class="width-800 color-gray">Who Cares</p>
</div>
<div class="float-right width-Half">
   <p class="width-800 color-gray opacity-80perc"><span class="color-red hover-opacity-100perc">John</span> Thomas</p>
   <p class="color-gray">Boss</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Positioning */

.float-left{
   float:left
}

.center{
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}

/* Size */

.width-800{
   width:800;
}

.half{
    width:50%;
}


/* etc */
```

**My Question:**

Is the generalized class approach a generally acceptable method in CSS? Can this be an efficient way to style a large project?

---

The generalized class approach offers readability and (in the long run) lessened number of classes required by a project, but at the expense of HTML readability.

Maybe there are some other pros/cons to it that I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, generalized classes is not such a swell idea.

A class name should generally describe the intention of the markup, not the exact styles that are applied. If you are using generalized classes it's pretty much the same thing as putting the CSS in inline styles in each element. The style sheet would become just a translation from class names to the corresponding style, and all the layout is in the HTML instead of in the style sheet where it should be.